# How to start a web browser as a "shell"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, window-manager, kiosk

I would like to **better** run a media player on my Linux (Ubuntu 16.04), connected via HDMI to a TV.

Today I use Kodi:

- it is started via a systemd service (`ExecStart = /usr/bin/xinit /root/.xinitrc`)
- `/root/.xinitrc` is simply `exec /usr/bin/kodi`

This is not an ideal setup but it works.

I would like now to switch to Emby (which runs in a browser) and at the same time have a more robust setup.

Specifically, I would like to:

- use a minimalist window manager, which would only start Chrome in kiosque mode
- make sure that exiting Emby restart it (by restarting the session)

**How to do that in a modern way?**

1. There are no security constraints - the only goal I want to achieve is to have Emby starting when the machine reboots, and then if it is closed by mistake have it restart.
2. There are no other GUI applications/windows which run on the machine (it is otherwise a server which provides web services and APIs). Emby is the only graphical program supposed to be used on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your minimalist window manager, upon startup, to run

`chrome --kiosk http://localhost:8096/web/home.html`

That starts the Emby client within Chrome.

For example, for the Awesome window manager,
in `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua` or `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua`, append
`awful.util.spawn("chrome --kiosk http://localhost:8096/web/home.html")`